# Ajax form occasionally adds data to URL instead of POST then redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I am having an issue with a form created recently. It seems that it will not work as designed each and every time and is inconsistent during testing itself. I have been unable to determine the problem even after much searching and different attempts to rewrite the JavaScript function.

hopefully with the help of StackOverflow someone can see the faults in this and offer some advice.

HTML FORM:

```js
//I am using jQuery
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>


<script>

// Processing hidden fields for campaign tracking information
    function getCamp(name) {
        var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        return (results && results[1]) || undefined;
    }
    var camp = getCamp('utm_campaign');
    if (camp > '') {
        console.log( 'got it: ' + camp);
        document.getElementById('report-camp').value = camp;
    } else {
        console.log('campaign is missing');
    }

    var lpurl = document.location.href;
    document.getElementById('report-url').value = lpurl;



$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {

        var formData = {
            'first-name'   : $('input[name=first-name]').val(),
            'last-name'    : $('input[name=last-name]').val(),
            'phone'        : $('input[name=phone').val(),
            'email'        : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'report-phone' : $('input[name=report-phone').val(),
            'report-camp'  : $('input[name=report-camp').val(),
            'report-url'   : $('input[name=report-url').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/xxxxxx/xxxx/', 
            data        : formData, // object
            encode      : true
        })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log(data); 
                window.location = "/thank-you";
            });
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>
```

```html
<form id="contact-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="report-phone" value="<?php echo $dynamic_phone; ?>">
    <input id="haa-camp" type="hidden" name="report-camp" value="organic">
    <input id="haa-url" type="hidden" name="report-url" value="n/a">
    <div class="form-icons">
        <h4>Form Headline</h4>
        <p>Why you should fill out the form</p>

        <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-label">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </span>
            <input class="input-group-field" name="first-name" type="text" placeholder="First name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-label">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </span>
            <input class="input-group-field" name="last-name" type="text" placeholder="Last name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-label">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                    </span>
            <input class="input-group-field" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-label">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    </span>
            <input class="input-group-field" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" required>
        </div>
    </div>


    <button class="button form-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> &nbsp; Get Help Today
    </button>

</form>
```

Again some of the time this function works perfectly, other times it results in the form data being placed into the URL like so: 
https://example.com/?report-phone=123-456-7890&report-camp=Primay-Lead-Source-Mobile&report-url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Fgeo%3DPrimary%26utm_source%3DGAW%26utm_campaign%3DPrimary-Lead-Source-Mobilee&first-name=john&last-name=doe&email=jdoe%40testform.com&phone=123-000-0000

Any thoughts would be appreciated and thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Sounds like there is either an error being thrown in your code or form doesn't exist when you try to add the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to submit form using standard html submit with default method 'GET' and also using ajax. I created a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/mzetykv6/2/) for you that uses only ajax request. In this case data always would be sent via POST.

```
<button id="getHelpBtn"class="button form-button" type="button" value="Submit">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> &nbsp; Get Help Today
    </button>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#getHelpBtn').click(function(event) {

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/xxxxxx/xxxx/',
        data: $('#contact-form').serialize(), // object
        encode: true
      })
      // using the done promise callback
      .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        window.location = "/thank-you";
      });
  });

});
```